# Same output claim from multiple technical profiles

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

If the same output claim is defined in multiple technical profiles, what is the expected behavior?

Particularly if a technical profile emits an output claim and another technical profile that executes later defines the same output claim but does not emit one at run time, what is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If there are two different OrchestrationSteps, each containing a TechnicalProfile that emits the same claim, then the TechnicalProfile from the later step will "overwrite" the value of the claim *if such a claim is emitted*.

Lets take a specific (although somewhat made-up) example.

Step 1 uses a TechnicalProfile for a SelfAsserted page that asks the user for their first name via "OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName"" . The user fills in the name "John" on this page, and continues.

Step 2 uses a TechnicalProfile for a ClaimsExchange with Google, which *may* also emit a first name via "OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName"".

However, it is possible that the user did or did not register their first name when creating their account at Google. If the first name is available (lets say with the name "Lingeshwaran"), then Google will emit that claim, and B2C will consume it. In this case, the final resulting value after step 2 for givenName will be "Lingeshwaran".

If the user did not fill in their first name when creating their Google account, then it will be missing from the claims that Google emits in their token. As a result, the existing "givenName" claim will not be overwritten, and the resulting value after step 2 for givenName will be "John".

Comment: Thanks John. This is helpful.

Comment: @LingeshwaranPalaniappan, can you please upvote John's answer and flag the question as answered.

Comment: Apparently I dont have enough credits to upvote :) How do i mark it as answered?